# Hazelcast L2 cache slow

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hazelcast

I'm using Hibernate L2 cache with Hazelcast in versions Hibernate 5.3.2 and Hazelcat 3.10.4 with the hazelcast-all and hibernate-jcache dependencies and Spring in 5.0.6. Also tried recent Hibernate 5.4.0 and Hazelcat 3.11.1.

I've got a not very complex or deep ERM with about at all ~7000 (cached) objects in database. I configured the entities and collections with @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE) and nicely as aimed at no single sqls are executed when getting the cached data.

So far so good, but the performance is unacceptable, e.g. without the L2 caching ~4s to get the entities, with Hazelcast L2 cache in place no performance gain at all!
With Ehcache, which is not an option in my clustered environment, the preformance is great, under 500ms, on the same query and the with same Hibernate configuration (just changed the 'hibernate.cache.region.factory_class').

As far as I see the reason could not be the cluster network traffic, because it is already slow on my local machine with only 1 knot.

Nothting special about the Hazelcast config, the Hazelcast L2 client config looks like this

```
<hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config hazelcast-client-config-3.10.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<instance-name>hazelcast-l2-client</instance-name>
  <group>
    <name>${HZGroupName}</name>
    <password>${HZGroupPassword}</password>
  </group>
  <network>
    <cluster-members>
      <address>${HZLocalAddress}</address>
      <address>${HZMemberAddress}</address>
    </cluster-members>
  </network>
</hazelcast-client>
```

Hibernate config

```
jpaAdditionalProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory");
jpaAdditionalProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
```

So I am a bit clueless now and cannot belive that Hazelcast is that slow, probably I missed a configuration to speed things up. Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: `jpaAdditionalProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");` ? Are you sure you should not be referencing some Hazelcast-related class here?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I corrected this to org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory

Comment: Can you confirm if the entries are written to / read from Hazelcast? You can configure management center URL and check it from there.

Comment: Looks like Hazelcast may not be used at all -since there's no performance change- have you checked the docs and made sure your setup is correct? https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Hazelcast L2 is used and data definitely comes from the cache. You can see the caches and warm up in the Mancenter:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wKq6rDMJdOvM_QmKO-5q25c6PyW7E7Kn/view?usp=sharing
and the cache misses and hits in the hibernate logs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HdP0PwvnmTJYL2CWFzeNSwuSTqBZibS-/view?usp=sharing
You could also have a look at the screenshot of xrebel analyse:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FEtb1rW-zwyIr2hIBo8bVwEp8VSvjztO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Because I'm still clueless with Hazelcast, I gave it a try with Apache Ignite V2.7. I replaced the L2 cache with Ignite in a local 1 knot setup according to the Hazelcast one (I had to downgrade Hibernate to 5.1 but no ORM or other changes)  ...performance goes up, satisfiable by well below 1s. And also still at <1s highering the amount of entites by a factor of 4.

Answer (score 1):

@Labtax, you need to set these properties too so that your Hibernate L2 cache uses Hazelcast:

```
jpaAdditionalProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory");
jpaAdditionalProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_native_client", "true");
```

Please give it a try with these properties.

Comment: Displaimer: I am a co-worker of the OP and thus also involved in the Hazelcast problems. Our projects already uses Hibernate 5.x which is incompatible to `com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory`(it relies on `org.hibernate.cache.QueryResultsRegion` which seems to be gone since Hibernate 4). For this reason, our setup is based on the JCacheRegionFactory. And in general, the L2 cache seems to be used because there really are no SQL statements logged (they appear when we disable our Hazelcast JPA config). This said, your proposed solution does not work for us :-(

Comment: Edit: Just found a new version of the hazelcast-hibernate dependency. Maybe it will work with that one and your settings.

Comment: OK, after switching to hazelcast-hibernate53 and replacing hazelcast-all with only needed modules, it also works with your parameters. And yes, using the native client seems to improve the cache performance by around 20%. Changing from Hazelcast 3.10.4 to 3.11.1 also seems to give again 20%improvement, so we could reduce the request times by around 36%. Still far away from what we can see with other tools, but all in all not too bad. Thanks!

Comment: @Markus K, if you use embedded Hazelcast, since there wont be any network traffic, It’ll be alot faster. Remove the second param I shared & use a hazelcast.xml file, not hazelcast-client.xml. You’ll see that it’s alot more faster.